# How can I implement modifiable products (which are subscriptions) in Shopify?

Tags: shopify

I've implemented subscriptions through ReCharge where users can select products and these are saved as line item properties for that product. This was the only solution I could think of with my limited time using Shopify.

Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660862/update-remove-cart-attributes-in-shopify), it seems like line item properties are read-only after checkout. If this is truly the case, is there any solution that enables having modifiable subscriptions where users can re-select products for that subscription product that I can implement?

I'm using Shipstation for the shipping piece if this matters at all.

Comment: Are you trying to do this using Shopify API?

Comment: @GustavoStraube - by whatever means really to get my shop to have it where a user can login, go to my account, change the line item properties for their subscription.

Comment: I got it. ReCharge is very limited in terms of customization. It allows the user to change only the quantity and frequency for each subscription. If you need to enable some update beyond that, you'll probably need to rely on a custom solution. Unfortunately that's what I did recently.

Comment: @GustavoStraube - how did you end up doing it? Could you elaborate because that's what I'm seeking.

Comment: Actually, I discarded the use of ReCharge and wrote a new subscription application based on the client needs. It's not a simple solution, though.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I implement modifiable products (which are subscriptions) in Shopify?

You can't. Well, technically you can but it is not easily done. Since you indicated that you're looking for official answers, I've contacted *Shopify* via email for you and I've been discussed this with Brad Leclerc, where he said:

> That is indeed the case with line item properties being read-only after checkout, so it would need to be reconstructed for the new order. There's no super quick/easy to do that without some custom development to automate the process. If you end up wanting to do that, I'm sure a developer from http://experts.shopify.com could set something like that up.

You have two choices, either hire someone from [experts.shopify.com](http://experts.shopify.com) to help or build your own marketing script from scratch.

Proof of email: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3wC5.png

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this with meta fields on the customer.

1. meta fields can be used on the subscription product template to make it sensitive to the state of the customer's subscription (new or existing)
2. Use a order web hook to detect when a new subscription product has been purchased and then update the customer meta fields (e.g. subscription level and start and end dates).
3. use a periodic task in your supporting private app to:

   - prompt user before subscription becomes due to update their payment details or cancel the subscription
   - create and bill new orders for each subscription period

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Shopify, nor Revcharge, but according to the references, couldn't you simply customize the product page in shopify?

https://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/page-specific/product-page/get-customization-information-for-products

According RevCharge, you should use a Shopify product template anyway..
http://recharge.helpscoutdocs.com/article/91-recharge-integration-guide

Comment: This is for post checkout though, not on the initial checkout. So editing line properties on a subscription product AFTER it's been ordered.

Comment: If may I ask, why would a customer change item properties after he/she placed the order?

Comment: I'm creating products which are subscriptions, and inside of each subscription the customer can choose multiple products. The only way that I know in order to make this happen with Recharge is to store those products as line-item properties. If you can suggest any other method which has a stable recurring charging system I'd be open to it.